# How to build this regex?

Tags: regex

I want to match the emails in following texts,

```
uma@cs.stanford.edu - match
uma at cs.Stanford.edu - match
http://infolab.stanford.edu/~widom/yearoff.h
we
genale.stanford.edu
n <A href="mailto:cheriton@cs.stanford.edu - match
hola   @  kirti.edu - match
```

Now I want to capture 2 parts of email address only like (uma) and (cs.stanford) in the email uma@cs.stanford.edu.

My current pattern is  :

```
(\w+)[(\s+at\s+)|(\s*@\s*)]+(\w+|\w+\.\w+).edu
```

But it matches the string - `infolab.stanford.edu` - which I don't want.
Can anybody suggest any modification on this?

Comment: What do you want matched out of the `mailto:` line?  Which dialect of regex are you using — what's the host language?  The answers will differ between JavaScript, Python, C++, Ruby, C, Perl, Java, various dialects of SQL and PHP, to name but a few of the many possibilities.  And for C, there are multiple possible regex packages, such as PCRE, or POSIX, or HS, or ...

Comment: Note that the square brackets form a funny character class in your regex.  You use round brackets (parentheses) to enclose alternatives, not square brackets.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: i used parentheses but it captures the 'at' or @ which I don't need. Is there any way, i can group and not capturing there?

Comment: Since you've not identified the dialect of regex you're using, I don't know.  It matters; PCRE (Perl compatible regular expressions) have ways of suppressing captures, but many other regex packages don't.  I'm far from convinced you need the parentheses around `(\s+at\s+)` or `(\s*@\s*)`, so that capturing should be immaterial.  Note that the real regex for matching email addresses is about a mile long.  See [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323)!  Note the third answer.

Comment: Your character class is wrong, or probably shouldn't be there at all. `[(\s+at\s+)|(\s*@\s*)]` is equivalent to `[+*|()at@\s]` - ie it matches any 1 of all the characters between square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you understand that this regex doesn't verify the correctness of your email address, but merely acts as a quick first line of defense against malformed addresses, an easy fix to your regex is as follows:

```
([\w.]+)(?:\s+at\s+|\s*@\s*)(\w+|\w+\.\w+).edu
```

In particular your regex was missing addresses with usernames containing `.` (which for example my main email address uses), as well as had a messed up middle part (pretending it's a character class and something weird about letting it repeat??).

Comment: I am using regex in python. The expression provided captures the 'at' and '@' which I don't need.

Comment: Updated, but keep in mind you were capturing them too. Your syntax was just so wrong it didn't even process it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for your sample input:

```
(\w+) *(?:@|\bat\b) *(\S+)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/8Xcgy2muuTn4xa).

Regex breakdown:

- `(\w+)` one or more word chars
- `*` zero or more spaces (could use `\s*`, but no need)
- `(?:...)` non capturing group (to leave username in group 1 and domain in group 2)
- `@|\bat\b` either `@` or `at` as a solitary word (`\b` means word boundary), so it doesn't match the `at` in `match`
- `(\S+)` one or more non-whitespace

This assumes usernames are only word chars (letters, digits and the underscore). To work more generally, and dots and dashes:

```
([\w.-]+) *(?:@|\bat\b) *(\S+)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your current regex is that you try to use `[` `]` as a group. Square brackets indicate a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), not a group. If you swap these out for `(` `)` you'll notice that your regex matches the desired result.

This results in the regex:

```
(\w+)((\s+at\s+)|(\s*@\s*))+(\w+|\w+\.\w+).edu
```

Optionally you could choose to remove some unnecessary groups:

```
(\w+)(\s+at\s+|\s*@\s*)+(\w+|\w+\.\w+).edu
```